# Converting a table of mixed numeric-string content to an array

Tags: matlab

I have a table with mixed numeric&string content:

```
M = 

    rep           file           condition    corrAns
    ___    __________________    _________    _______

    1      'stimuli/03C1.wav'    'C1'         2      
    1      'stimuli/03C4.wav'    'C4'         1 
......................
```

I'd like to convert M to an array, so as to be able to save it as a spreadsheet using `xlswrite`, which requires an array as input.

However, the command `table2array(M)` gives the error

```
Cannot concatenate the table variables 'rep' and 'file', because their types are double and cell.
```

I tried converting the first and final columns from double to cell using

```
M(:,1) = table2cell(M(:,1))
```

or even

```
for i_row=1:row_N
    M(i_row,1) = num2cell(M(i_row,1));
    M(i_row,4) = num2cell(M(i_row,4));
end
```

but both of these conversions lead to the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't `M = table2cell(M);` work?

Comment: Arghhh, I knew it was something banal like this - thank you very much!

Comment: Just use `writetable` to save the table directly to an Excel file.  There's no need to convert to a cell array first.

Comment: Yes - even better. Thanks!